# "handleError is not a function" error running sql.js

Tags: javascript, sqlite, browser, sql.js

I'm trying to implement a REST environment in which, on the client side, client data is stored in a SQLite database.

I have accomplished this before on Cordova using [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage), but I'm unable to accomplish the same using its vanilla-JS counterpart, [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/)

The problem I have is that the `Database()` function isn't returning anything, so I can't do any kind of query.

This is my test file (test.html):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/kripken/sql.js/master/js/sql.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var sql             = window.SQL;
            var db              = sql.Database(); // Is returning undefined ?
            
            sqlstr = "CREATE TABLE hello (a int, b char);";
            sqlstr += "INSERT INTO hello VALUES (0, 'hello');"
            sqlstr += "INSERT INTO hello VALUES (1, 'world');"
            db.run(sqlstr); // Run the query without returning anything

            var res = db.exec("SELECT * FROM hello");

            console.log(res);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This returns the following error:

> TypeError: this.handleError is not a function
>   sql.js
>   Line 466

If I create `this.handleError()` by myself, the error changes to:

> TypeError: db is undefined
>   test.html
>   Line 13

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? I have looked all over the place, but documentation seems to be scarce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sql.Database()` needs to be called as a constructor (*e.g.* `db = new sql.Database();`). Note the `new`, as in the [Usage example](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/#usage).

```js
var sql = window.SQL;
var db = new sql.Database();

sqlstr = "CREATE TABLE hello (a int, b char);";
sqlstr += "INSERT INTO hello VALUES (0, 'hello');"
sqlstr += "INSERT INTO hello VALUES (1, 'world');"
db.run(sqlstr);

var res = db.exec("SELECT * FROM hello");

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kripken/sql.js/master/js/sql.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed that!